# Am I safely mutating in my akka actors or is this not thread safe?

Tags: scala, akka

I am a little confused if I am safely mutating my mutable maps/queue inside of my actor.

Can someone tell me if this code is thread-safe and correct?

```
class SomeActor extends Actor {
  val userQ = mutable.Queue.empty[User]
  val tranQ = mutable.Map.empty[Int, Transaction]

  def receive = {
    case Blank1 =>
      if(userQ.isEmpty) 
        userQ ++= getNewUsers()
    case Blank2 =>
      val companyProfile = for {
         company <- api.getCompany() // Future[Company]
         location <- api.getLoc() // Future[Location]
      } yield CompanyProfile(company, location)

      companyProfile.map { cp => 
        tranQ += cp.id -> cp.transaction   // tranQ mutatated here
      }
  }
}
```

Since I am mutating the tranQ with futures, is this safe?

It is my understanding that each actor message is handled in a serial fashion, so although maybe frowned upon I can use mutable state like this.

I am just confused if using it inside of a future call like tranQ is safe or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, your code is not safe.

While an actor processes one message at a time, you will lose this guarantee as soon as `Future`s are involed. At that point, the code inside the `Future` is executed on a (potentially) different thread and the next message might be handled by the actor.

A typical pattern to work around this issue is to send a message with the result of the `Future` using the `pipeTo` pattern, like so:

```
import akka.pattern.pipe

def receive: Receive {
  case MyMsg =>
    myFutureOperation()
     .map(res => MyMsg2(res))
     .pipeTo(self)
  case MyMsg2(res) =>
    // do mutation now
}
```

More information about using `Future`s can be found in akka's documentation: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/scala/futures.html